# Как правильно задекларировать глобальные переменные в заголовочном файле .h в Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, переменные

Без использования `@property @synthesis`.
Есть код с геттером и сеттером.

***main.m***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "UsingClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Запуск программы");
        UsingClass *UsC = [[UsingClass alloc]init];
        [UsC setX:121];
        NSLog(@"поле x = %d", [UsC getX]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***UsingClass.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UsingClass: NSObject    

-(void) setX: (int)x1;    
-(int) getX;

@end
```

***UsingClass.m***

```
#import "UsingClass.h"    

int x = 5; //некоторые глобальные переменные
int y = 10;   

@implementation UsingClass

-(void) setX: (int)x1
{
    x = x1; 
}

-(int) getX {
    return x;
}

@end
```

В таком варианте всё работает. Стоит переписать глобальные переменные в h. класс (то есть переменные записать перед секцией `@interface` в `UsingClass.h`, стерев их же из `.m`)  как всё рушится с ошибкой:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Из всего вышесказанного мне не понятно:

1. Почему сия ошибка получается?
2. Как правильно задекларировать глобальную переменную в h. файле? И можно ли это сделать?

Comment: а при чем тут @property к глобальной переменной?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko не причем. Просто сеттер и геттер можно создать с помощью `@property @Syntesis` а не так как я.

Comment: зачем вам сеттер и геттер для глобальной переменной?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Разумеется чтобы установить значение и получить значение.

Comment: это какое то сильно извращенное издевательство над инкапсуляцией?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko оу, я может просто путаюсь в терминологии. Там где я напейсал глобальная переменная, читайте поле класса.

Comment: тогда можете объявить переменную как static, и написать сеттер и геттер примерно так `+(int)x;` и `+(void)setX:(int)x;`, либо создать синглтон (или добавить в существующий, например AppDelegate)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала ее надо объявить где то (main.m отличное место)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int x;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Потом объявить ее еще раз в любом .h файле (на этот раз как extern)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

extern int x;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

...

@end
```

и потом уже использовать в любом месте, предварительно импортировав указанный выше .h файл

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    x = 1;

    ....
```

Помните, что переменную нельзя присваивать в .h файле, поскольку тогда компилятор будет ругаться на 'duplicate symbol'

Ну и в целом глобальные переменные - плохая практика.

Comment: а как тогда без глобальных переменных? 
Что-то кажется, что вы мне предлагаете не то, что требуется. Я как-то декларировал в h глобальные переменные, без вами предложенных действий. Всё работало. Почему теперь не работает - в ум взять не могу. 
Хотя может я тупо путаюсь в терминологии. Может речь идёт не о глобальных переменных, а о полях класса. (В java просто эти определения тождественны, насчёт objective-c не уверен).